# Datatables, where to write custom HTML code for individual row formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database, datatable

I am using datatables to show JSON data in fancy cards layout. I am using DT's `render` method to churn out card's HTML code:

```
"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {  
   var formattedHTMLRow = "<div title = '" + row.title + "'>"+ row.service_name + "<p>" + row.category_name + "</p>" + "</div>";
   return serviceNameColumn;
}
```

The `formattedHTMLRow` is a watered down version of actual HTML code required to create card view. I dont want to write a lot of HTML code in Javascript.

Ideally, I want to load a *.html file with HTML template and get `render` method to use it. How do I do that?

Comment: You can check out any templating engines for JS, I use [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) but there are other alternatives such as [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

Comment: @TasosK. thats right, however I am looking for a simpler solution to quickly bind HTML template with `render` method.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you need, you want to import a file that has some big HTML code in it, change it and then render it on a datatables column, right?

I've written a simple plunkr which do exactly that, check it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/99ux1uF3DPW1k7T5Ovq7?p=preview

It uses the `link` tag with `rel='import'` for specifying which file we wan't to load, and use it with simple javascript later on the DataTable's render method.

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory, if you need extra information just ask.

Further reading:

- [HTML5 Imports: Import HTML Files Into HTML Files](http://www.noupe.com/development/html5-imports-import-html-files-into-html-files-83467.html)

Hope it helps you!

Comment: +1 for `import`. Didnt knew you could do that. A really good solution. I would give the `<link>` an id like `id="partial"` - `var partial = document.getElementById("partial").import` works too, makes it a little bit easier with multiple templates.